# How to set source of the image a variable in a pug template?

Tags: html, image, pug

While creating a movie info platform, I wanted to print image posters. I was unable to set the source of the image to a variable in pug.

```
      each movie in movies
         .col-md-3(style="margin-bottom: 20px;")
             .text-center
                img(src= "#{movie.Poster}" style="width:100%; height:200px; padding: 0px 40px;")
                    h5(style="padding: 5px 40px 0px 40px;") #{movie.Title}
                    h5 #{movie.Year}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have image source stored in `movie.Poster`, then I think you should try something like this:

```
img(src=movie.Poster)
```

You can read more about [attribute interpolation](https://pugjs.org/language/attributes.html#attribute-interpolation) in the Pug documentation.